# MySql setting that allows "" to be equal to null or 0?

Tags: mysql

I've got a MySQL server running on linux and another on Windows, both containing duplicate copies of a database table. The table is defined like:

```
parent_id - int(10) - nullable - default=null
title - varchar(100)
```

I can execute this sql on Linux, and it works fine (I know, it's wrong and horrible and shouldn't work, but it does). Inserting a 0 into in the parent ID, but on Windows an error is thrown saying to use the right syntax near "":

```
insert into some_table (parent_id, title) values ("", "Some string")
```

Is there a MySQL setting that tells the Linux version to accept a "" as a valid int?

**EDIT**

I want it to be known that I agree, making the above work just plain sick. It's wrong in every way - but it's something I have to deal with. I'm tasked with maintaining a poorly written PHP product that depends on the above type of SQL statement being able to execute.

**EDIT 2**

What's interesting is that in the console, MySQL on Linux throws a warning saying "Incorrect integer value ''" - yet it still inserts the record. MySQL on Windows throws the message but doesn't do the insert. So somehow, MySQL on Linux is setup to ignore errors... does anyone know where this setting resides?

Comment: That would fit in what I call "horrible programming practices". What's the reason why one would keep on pushing a string to ultimately store an int?

Comment: To be short, the original programmer had a bug that he couldn't fix. His parent_id was null, and he didn't like it blowing up when the sql said (, "Some String") - so he made it so "" worked as 0 and then fixed his null problem this way. Lazy bugger... so now I have to deal with it.

Comment: What does it do if, on your windows system, you replace the `"` with `'`? That could actually be caused by a difference in SQL-standard compliance (like your Windows system would be ANSI-compliant whereas the one on Linux would be more flexible)

Comment: @Romain - The double quotes work in cases for strings so I'm going to assume the ANSI-compliance isn't an issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I never did find the setting in MySQL that allows this. Not that I'm too broken up about it. I talked the client into giving more time to making the app correct and simply removed all the poorly written code that relied on the setting.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) or [IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function to fix your statement rather than changing a MySQL setting.

Comment: The code I'm maintaining is littered with the above messy sql statements. I'm just told to get it working as quickly as possible on the new server... so the MySQL setting is what I need. I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Because the column is defined with a default, you can omit specifying it in the insert statement.

Sorry, maybe i misread your problem. Are you trying to insert a zero as the value for `parent_id` ?

Comment: Yeah, putting in "" causes the server to accept it as a 0. The column's default is null.

Answer (score 0):

Simply dont set the parent_id value.

`insert into some_table (title) values ("Some string")`